# Is `input` a directive or a step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

> The input directive on a stage allows you to prompt for input, using
>   the input step. ..

(cit. Pipeline Syntax, Jenkins User Documentation https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#input)

So is `input` actually a directive, or a step? How to understand phrase "using
the input step"

Pipeline used here (extract):

```
stage('StageName') {
    when { environment name: 'VAR1', value: 'true' }
    steps {
        input {
            message: "press OK to continue"
        }
        dir('doithere') {
            git url: gitcoord[0], branch: gitcoord[1], credentialsId: gitcoord[2] 
            cmd('ls -alh') 
        }
    }
}
```

Run-time:

```
WorkflowScript: 336: Expected a step @ line 336, column 34.
                       message: "press OK to continue"
                                ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In declarative pipeline, you have to put it directly below the `stage` level ("directive"). Then it is in the form `input { .. }`.

In scripted pipelines (or `script` blocks in declarative pipelines), it exists as a normal step. The syntax then is `input(..)`:

```
stage('StageName') {
    when { environment name: 'VAR1', value: 'true' }
    steps {
        dir('doithere') {
            git url: gitcoord[0], branch: gitcoord[1], credentialsId: gitcoord[2] 
            cmd('ls -alh') 
            input(message: "press OK to continue")
            cmd('rm -rf *')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below one worked for me:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('stage1') {
            input {
                message "press OK to continue"
            }
            steps {
                sh "mkdir dir1"
                dir("dir1") {
                    sh "echo 'Hello'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, me supposed that. Unfortunately it's not what's needed. The need is to pause pipeline execution for user input directly before step selected by pipeline developer.